# Qualify MathJax expressions

Tags: mathjax, mathematical-expressions

Can anybody tell me if exists any way to **qualify** mathematical expressión written in **MathJax**, I mean, I want to use a program which in real time take the mathematical procedures and detect if there were mistakes or not.

Answer (score 1):

mathJax is just for render purpose, and you can write just about anything. However it exists tools for Latex. This link might interest you:

https://calculator-algebra.org/cgi-bin/calculator?request=calculator&

Developped by [Todor Milev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515446/todor-milev). See also [Is there a calculator with LaTeX-syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219121/is-there-a-calculator-with-latex-syntax/26390497#26390497)

Hope this helps