# How to perform calculations in text with RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

Is it possible to perform simple calculations in text with RMarkdown? For example when typing:

```
...compound A (50 mg, ?0.05/2? mmol) was added...
```

where ? is some syntax to let RMarkdown know that it needs to calculate what is in between rather than just exporting it as text, to get in the word output file:

...compound A (50 mg, 0.025 mmol) was added...

I found this relevant question about LaTeX: [Is there a calculator with LaTeX-syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219121/is-there-a-calculator-with-latex-syntax) but dont know if it is possible in RMarkdown. It seems like an obvious feature to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include R code inline by enclosing your expression with `` `r ` ``. That is, if you put the following in your RMarkdown (.Rmd):

```
...compound A (50 mg, `r 0.05/2` mmol) was added...
```

It will render as:

```
...compound A (50 mg, 0.025 mmol) was added...
```

For more detail see

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html and

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html